Pullback of the canonical divisor along blowup of a singular surface and intersection numbers
Given $X$ a normal projective surface over $\mathbb{C}$ and $p$  be a singular point of $X$ . Let $\pi: Y \rightarrow X$ be the blowup of $X$ at the point $p$. Is it true that $\pi^{\star}(K_{X}) \cdot E=0$ where $K_{X}$ is the canonical divisor on X. This is true for smooth surfaces.
For example, to resolve the singularity $x^2+y^3+z^{10}+xyz=0 \subset \mathbb{A}^3$ at origin, we need to blowup the origin consequently four times. Now, in order to compute the self intersections of exceptional divisors, I need to know whether $\pi^{\star}(K_{X}) \cdot E=0$ so that I can use adjunction formula.
Is there a general way to compute these self intersections for normal surfaces?
Can we get some intuition for this particular example?

This is true if the singularity is Gorenstein (or $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein). Otherwise, it is not clear how to define the pullback of the canonical divisor.

What exactly is your problem?
